# existing of limiting point and delta exist

Tags: real-analysis

If $\lim_{x \to p} f(x)  =  L $  and If p is the limited point  and p $\in R$, is this imply there exist of $\delta$? and 
$$|p-x| < \epsilon$$
$$|f(x)-L| < \delta$$

or condition(limited point ) is not enough to say this?

Comment: The definition of $lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L$ is that: For all positive number $\epsilon$, we can find another positive number $\delta$ such that if $|x-p|<\delta$, then $|f(x) - L|<\epsilon$.

Comment: Do you know the way to prove this 'definition' ? just curious

Comment: What does $\lim_{x\to p} f(x) = L$ mean to you?

Answer (score 1):

"$\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=L$" is a shorthand way of expressing that for any $\epsilon>0$ that you choose, there exists some $\delta$ such that whenever $x$ is within a distance $\delta$ of $p$, $f(x)$ is within $\epsilon$ of $L$. In the real numbers, we measure the distance between two numbers $a,b$ by taking $|a-b|$ (there are, of course, other notions of distance for other kinds of spaces and even other notions of distance over the real numbers if you like, but this is the usual one). So, yes, $\lim_{x\to p}f(x)=L$ implies that as soon as you choose an $\epsilon$, a corresponding $\delta$ exists such that $|x-p|<\delta$ implies $|f(x)-L|<\epsilon$. In fact, it implies that there are infinitely many such $\delta$'s: observe that if $\delta$ satisfies this condition then so does $\delta/2$.